# Looking to round figures in a column

Tags: mysql

Looking to do a mathematical equation in SQL to reduce cost by `3%`. My column is named `A2` in table cost. What I have is this:

```
update Cost set A2 = (A2 * .97)
```

But I want it to round, so if the formula comes out to 1.9875 I want it to round to `1.99`, or if it comes out to `1.9843` I want it to round to `1.98`.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE cost SET A2 = ROUND(A2*.97, 2)
```

The second argument is the number of decimal places you want it to round to.

Comment: That worked perfect.